# Can't retrieve a one to many relationship in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

I'm trying to get to a ProfileType through my User model, i.e. $user->profile->profiletype; I'm not able to retrieve an object, however. Basically, User hasOne Profile, and Profile belongsTo User and ProfileType. ProfileType hasMany Profile.

My table names are users, profiles and profile_types.

### models/User.php

```
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User as SentryUserModel;

class User extends SentryUserModel {

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should soft delete.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $softDelete = true;

    public function profile()
    {
            return $this->hasOne('Profile');
    }
}
```

### models/Profile.php

```
class Profile extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('username', 'slug', 'completed');

    /**
    * @return
    */
    public function user()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function profiletype()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('ProfileType');
    }
}
```

### models/ProfileType.php

```
class ProfileType extends Eloquent {

    /**
    * @return
    */
    public function profiles()
    {
            return $this->hasMany('Profile');
    }

}
```

### Profile and ProfileType migrations

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

// profile_types table

class CreateProfileTypesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profile_types', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id', true);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('profile_types');
    }

}

// profiles table

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id', true);
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->boolean('completed');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('profile_type_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('profiles');
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your migrations too please?

Comment: Have you tried loading it using something like  User::with('profile.profiletype')->get(); ?

Comment: @user1669496 I added my migrations to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have found a bug with the way Laravel handles foreign keys.  It should know that the foreign key of `profile_types` is `profile_type_id` but it's actually looking for `profiletype_id`.

So you can either change that column in your table so you don't have to worry about sending extra parameters each time you need another relationship on that table, or in your `Profile` model, you can make your function like this...

```
function profiletype
{
    return $this->belongsTo('ProfileType', 'profile_type_id');
}
```

Then you should be able to find a user's profile type with...

```
$user = User::find(1);
echo $user->profile->profiletype->name;
echo $user->profile->profiletype->slug;
```

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Will make an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Also having a similar bug with a similar structure (Issue & IssueStatus). This bug still appears in 4.1.28.