# Problems with relations between models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I cant get my relations between my models to work.

I have this situation in IRL:
A company release some ownership information once a year in a annual general meeting
The notes from the annual general meeting contains information about a persons ownership in the company

I have made these models and the relations between them:

```
class Company extends Eloquent{
    public function annualmeetings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('AnnualMeeting');
    }
}

class AnnualMeeting extends Eloquent{
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Company');
    }
    public function ownerships()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Ownership');
    }
}

class Ownership extends Eloquent{
    public function annualmeeting()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('AnnualMeeting');
    }
    public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Person');
    }
}

class Person extends Eloquent{
    public function ownerships()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Ownership');
    }
}
```

Now I want to take out all the companies a person has a ownership in and some information from the Company class some information from the Ownership class and a variable in the AnnualMeeting class

I have tried something like this:

```
$companies = Person::with('ownerships.annualmeeting.company')
```

But I do not get the data for the related models. What am I doing wrong?

<3

MORE INFO:
I have tried this:

```
foreach ($person->ownerships as $ownership)
    echo $ownership->annualmeeting->date
```

I get the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

And this:

```
$person = Person::with('ownerships.annualmeeting')->findOrFail($id);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($person);
echo '</pre>';
```

Gives this (in the result):

```
[relations:protected] => Array
                      (
                       [annualmeeting] => 
                       )
```

Is it more understandable? :)

Comment: `Person::with('ownerships.annualmeeting.company')` by itself is not a full valid query. You'd need `->get()` on the end or something to complete it. Also, `with()` will only eager load relationships -- you won't end on companies, you'll still have `Person` be the first object.

Are you getting any actual errors or what? More information.

Comment: Never mind!

It was the same bug as occured in this case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724773/cant-retrieve-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-laravel-4?rq=1